# Best practice to unidirectionally send data from an application to another

Tags: c++, node.js, udp

Let me explain my situation:

I have a (c++) module that gathers data from an application 1 at a rate of 10 times per second.

I have another (nodejs) application 2, that needs to get the data from that module.

My question is: What is the best cross-platform way to share data from the module so that the application 2 can read it?

My technique would be to write in a UDP socket from the module and to read this socket from the application 2. But since I have never done that I'm not sure that it is the best way to do it.

Comment: At least it's a way that would always work, even across different machines. With UDP, you'll have to care for errors yourself (such as packet losses, etc). TCP would do pretty much of that for you already (on the other hand, you need to detect package bounds yourself). If both applications are on the same machine, there are other options, too, such as shared memory, pipes, named pipes, data exchange via file or database, message queues (possibly OS provided, something like ZeroMQ, ...). How far these options are supported by node.js, I have no idea, though, not experienced with.

Comment: It is a stream of messages or does it update the same piece of data over and over?

Comment: Memory mapped file is another option.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin This is the same piece of data over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends:

### Intramachine

**Does the C++ module run on the same machine as the nodejs application?** Then the best way in my opinion would be to compile and load the C++ module as a native nodejs module. So your C++ application would become a shared library i.e. DLL for nodejs, which can be called directly from the nodejs i.e. javascript application, which could bet ordinary javascript objects via a promise for example. Then you should use the [NAPI from nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html), a nice to build productive template I use can be found [here](https://github.com/Superlokkus/spielwiese/tree/napi).

This should be much faster and safer to use than other classical IPC (Inter process commonucation) techniques, as shared memory or message piping.

### Intermachine

**However if your applications are running on different machines, including different machines on the same physical device like VMs,** you need some sort of network way. The only difference between the different machines/different physical computers and different machines/same physical computer, would be that in the later case you would use the so called loop back address, instead of a specific variable address. But from here it gets very broad of which call style, object serialization or transport protocol fits your case best, and is heavily opinion based.

A few to mention are

- HTTP with JSON (HTTP implies TCP, often miscalled REST)
- [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)
- Boost serial with UDP or TCP via boost ASIO

### Conclusion/Recommendation

Since you are already in a nodejs environment, where HTTP/JSON is common, I would either try to package your C++ module in a nodejs native module even tough it has to communicate with the other nodejs instance on the other machine. But HTTP/JSON is much more easier with nodejs, and you just forward the javascript objects from your C++ module.

Or you use boost beast or asio, for a native HTTP approach, but that would consume much time.

Comment: I have already thought about the C++ module as a native nodejs module but the fact is that the c++ file is directly loaded through the application it extracts the data from so I cannot compile it and load it directly in nodejs. However the intramachine part of your answer, especially the protocol buffer could be the solution. Thanks for taking the time to write such a complete answer.

Comment: If it is still intramachine (you said intramachine for grpc, but that is more for intermachine), boost process is also worth looking, since you could simply load a node native module and the library for your application, and have a protable way to use shared memory. Its the fastest method, but has some draw backs, like that you have to care about synchronisation and x86/x64 interwork.